# Getting max value in CouchDB

Tags: database, couchdb, max

i am trying to use CouchDB as my Database.
I have problem when i want to get max value from 50000 records.
What the best solution to find max value?

I use this reduce function :

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, key);
    return largest;
}
```

And this is my map function :

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.TYPE=="customer"){
       emit(doc._id.substring(0,8), doc._id);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is a really simple map function, assuming you've at least read the documentation or something.

Comment: Hello i updated my question. Now, the problem is how to get the result view without any key specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing reduce functions, you should not forget to account for the [`rereduce` parameter](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/views/intro.html?highlight=rereduce#reduce-rereduce). However, you don't really even need it for 2 reasons:

1) you can just use `descending=true` when you query the view and get the largest item. (so you wouldn't need a reduce step at all)

2) you can use the [builtin reduce function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#reducefun-builtin) `_stats` and get the max value w/o writing your own reduce function.

The advantage to just using the map function w/o the reduce function is that you can not only get the largest value, but also the document that contains that value.

Comment: Okay :D i get max value now, i am using descending=true and limit=1 in accessing my view.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: @fanjavaid could you share url or program for better understanding. I am not getting how to implement this.